# Macbook resetting itself when playing a game

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a problem with my MacBook Air 2017 and I need help.

I was playing *Heart of Iron 4* on my Macbook Air and all of sudden, my Macbook Air restarted itself.

I restarted it and now I have this annoying fan sound running all the time and my battery percentage disappeared, I went through the setting to enable "Show battery percentage" but it keeps disappearing after enabling it.

Can I fix it myself or do I have to go in-store to fix it?

Comment: It's a Macbook-Air, not Macbook-pro. Sorry, I tried putting Macbook-Air but the tags automatically put Macbook-Pro. BTW I'm using a 2017 Macbook-Air.

Comment: I have edited your question and change it to MacBook Air 2017

Comment: Is the MBA otherwise useable?

Comment: nvm, I fixed my problem by googling it. no need to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be a little late, this sounds like an overheating issue. I would advise you to try and keep it well ventilated, and if possible have it serviced, even diagnostically. For example, blow some compressed air to clear the dust.

I would also recommend someone open it up, and clean off the dust manually, as compressed air is barely sufficient to fix these issues. If you can, also try to install a a temperature monitor and fan control program. While you did manage to fix the symptom by resetting the management controller, this will come back.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just do an SMC reset on your MacBook Air.